# Error is undefined Express error middleware

Tags: javascript, express

The Express api error messages are being returned as undefined in the front end. So I'm unable to display an error message in the front end to alert users.

The error messages appear fine in the dev tools.

I am using Express Redux and auth middleware.

I can't work out where I have gone wrong. Any ideas why the error is undefined?

**Error message component** (error is undefined so won't appear)

```
{error && <Message variant='danger'>{error}</Message>}
```

**errorMiddleware.js**

```
const notFound = (req, res, next) => {
    const error = new Error(`Not Found - ${req.originalUrl}`)
    res.status(404)
    next(error)
}

const errorHandler = (err, req, res, next) => {
    const statusCode = res.statusCode === 200 ? 500 : res.statusCode
    res.status(statusCode)
    res.json({
        message: err.message,
        stack: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? null : err.stack
    })
}

export { notFound, errorHandler }
```

Correct error message in dev tools:

[image]

**Which matches the login api here:**

```
const authUser = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body

  const user = await User.findOne({ email })

  if (user && (await user.matchPassword(password))) {
    res.json({
      _id: user._id,
      name: user.name,
      email: user.email,
      isAdmin: user.isAdmin,
      token: generateToken(user._id),
    })
  } else {
    res.status(401)
    throw new Error('Invalid email or password')
  }
})
```

**User log in action:**

```
export const login = (email, password) => async(dispatch) => {
    try {
        dispatch({
            type: USER_LOGIN_REQUEST
        })
        const config = {
            headers: {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            }
        }
        const { data } = await axios.post('/api/users/login', { email, password }, config)
        dispatch({
            type: USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS,
            payload: data
        })
        localStorage.setItem('userInfo', JSON.stringify(data))
    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({
            type: USER_LOGIN_FAIL,
            payload:
              error.response && error.response.data.message
                ? error.response.data.message
                : error.message,
          })
    }
}
```

**server.js**

```
app.use(notFound)
app.use(errorHandler)
```

**User reducer**

```
import { USER_LOGIN_FAIL, USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS, USER_LOGOUT, USER_LOGIN_REQUEST } from '../constants/userConstants'

export const userLoginReducer = (state = { }, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case USER_LOGIN_REQUEST:
            return { loading: true }
        case USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS:
            return { loading: false, userInfo: action.payload }
        case USER_LOGIN_FAIL:
            return { loading: false, error: action.payLoad }
        case USER_LOGOUT:
            return { }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

**userRoutes.js**

```
import express from 'express'
const router = express.Router()
import { authUser, getUserProfile, registerUser } from '../controllers/userController.js'
import { protect } from '../middleware/authMiddleware.js'

router.route('/').post(registerUser)
router.post('/login', authUser)
router.route('/profile').get(protect, getUserProfile)

export default router
```

Comment: Where are you calling `authUser`?  Is it just regular middleware?  That is an async function which means when you `throw new Error('Invalid email or password')`, it will just reject the promise that the fucntion returns.  But Express does NOTHING for rejected promises - it never looks at the return value of middleware.  You must use `next(err)`, not `throw err` with Express to route to the error handler.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using react and react context hook? I guess yes, in that case, you need use a reducer to actualize error value with action.payload, for the USER LOGIN FAIL case.

Comment: Yes I am, I've added the code for the reducer